# Add querystring parameters to from class based detail view with Django

Tags: python, django

How can I modify a class based view to add querystring parameters to the view? (So that when the view response is returned, the querystring is in the address bar?

```
class MyDetailView(DetailView):
    """
    A detail view for retrieving a model object.
    """

    model = MyModel

    def some_function_to_modify_qs(self):
        # do something and return modified qs for response
```

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking. If I understad you correctly you want a parameter passed to the view, but what do you want to be the response? A url with the same parameter that was passed before? What for? It will be a good idea to post your relevant **url** conf and **models**.

Comment: Why do you want to add query parameters in the response that weren't there in the request? There are two ways of adding them: redirect to the current url with the querystring or use javascript in the template to manipulate it client side. But my feeling is there must be a better solution to the underlying issue.

Comment: Yeah i think I had a brain fart. My use case was that i wanted to hit the view and then dynamically add querystring values based on the view content. I forgot I could just pass the querystring when I called the URL that takes me to that view. So that is what i did. (i.e. I just added a querystring like so:`' {% url 'view_name %}'?value=some_value`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not entirely sure why you’d want to do this, you could pass the values into the template instead but to answer your question the following should work.

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect

#inside your get method
return redirect(request.get_full_path() + “?query=string”)
```